# Движок и модуль для работы с API картами

Tags: карты, модульность, база-данных, движок

Подскажите Движок и модуль для работы с API картами. Но не просто с гео точками, а для расширенной работы. Проще говоря, интегрировать карту в каталог данных для работы с ними.

**Обновление**

Хорошо. Нужно будет привязать список к карте, чтобы при нажатии на элементы списка соответствующий этому элементу списка маркер на карте менял цвет, например. При сортировке списка по району города надо, чтобы маркеры на карте остались только в этом районе.

Comment: @blackdrums, опишите, пожалуйста, связно необходимый функционал.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Ну что, может, подскажете? Хоть какую-нибудь инфу